# переменные в __setitem__ и __getitem__ class myName():

Tags: python, парсер

Хочу получить результат:

```
; передача значения в class myName()
myName['section_']['option_'] = 'value_'

; чтение значения из class myName()
myName['section_']['option_']
```

(словарь по факту не нужен, нужны имена section, option, и значение value, внутри класса,
далее все пойдет в ConfigParser)

Интуитивно понимаю как это должно работать, но почему-то не выходит.
Нашел пример, который работает со строками и записывает их в словарь, чуть поправил,
как мне вывести переменные уже в самом class myName()?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

class myName:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dict_ = {}
  
    def get(self):
        return self.dict_

    def __getitem__(self, *args):
        if self.dict_.get(args[0]):
            return self.dict_[args[0]]
        else:
            self.dict_[args[0]]={}
        return self.dict_[args[0]]

    def __setitem__(self, *args):
        self.dict_[args[0]]=args[1]
        return self.dict_[args[0]]

array = myName()
array['section_']['option_'] = 'value_'
print('...')
print(array['section_']['option_'])
print(array['section_'])
print(array.dict_)
print('...')
```

### Интуитивно что-то такое:

```
class myName:
    def __init__(self):
        print('__init__')

    def __getitem__(self, *arg):
        print('__getitem__')
        print(arg[0]) # выведет section_
        print(arg[1]) # выведет option_

    def __setitem__(self, *arg, val):
        print('__setitem__')
        print(arg[0]) # выведет section_
        print(arg[1]) # выведет option_
        print(val)    # выведет value_

array = myName()
array['section_']['option_'] = 'value_'
print(array['section_']['option_'])
```

Вот так конечно реально вывести, но нужно как выше...

```
array['section_', 'option_'] = 'value_'
array['section_', 'option_']
```

### Получится ли реализовать такой вариант?

```
class myName:
    def __init__(self):
        print('__init__')
        self.section = None
        self.option = None
        self.value = None

    def __iter__(self):
        try:
            self.iter += 1
        except:
            self.iter = 0
        return self.iter

    def __getitem__(self, *arg):
        print('__getitem__')
        try:
            arg[0]
            if   self.__iter__ == 0: self.section = arg[0]
            elif self.__iter__ == 1: self.option = arg[0]
            self.__getitem__()
        except:
            self.iter = 0
            if   self.__iter__ == 0: print(self.section)
            elif self.__iter__ == 1: print(self.section, self.option)
        return self.value
```

### объясните пожалуйста, как такое происходит:

```
class myName:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dict_ = {'sect1': {'opt1': 'val_1'}}

    def __getitem__(self, *args):
        print(args[0])
        print(self.dict_[args[0]])
        return self.dict_[args[0]]

array = myName()
print(array['sect1']['opt1'])
```

а на выводе:

```
sect1
{'opt1': 'val_1'}
val_1
```

почему при вызове `self.dict_[args[0]]` с помощью `print` результат один, а при помощи `return` другой?

Comment: Вы понимаете, что используя синтаксис `var[k1][k2]` Вы **никак** не передадите `k1` и `k2` в один вызов `__getitem__`?

Comment: Приведите пример. как Вы собираетесь это использовать.

Comment: а я и не собирался делать это за один вывод, я хотел сделать условие, если вывод 2 по итерации, то происходит действие, если первый, выход до второй итерации. единственное, не могу тогда понять как разделить `array['sect1']['opt1']` от `array['sect1']` ...

Comment: в один вызов можно передать только так :  var[k1, k2]

Comment: Как вообще отличить является ли объект на входе списком элементов, или это один текстовый элемент из букв?

Comment: Вы всё ещё не сказали, зачем Вам это надо. Есть ощущение, что Вы пытаетесь гвоздь забить микроскопом.

Comment: хочу в результате получить короткий и понятный вызов в коде, при этом чтобы была запись через ConfigParser в ini файл.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если Вы хотите "упростить" работу с классом `ConfigParser` (автоматическое создание секций, если их нет), то можно сделать так:

```py
from configparser import ConfigParser


class MyCfg(ConfigParser):  # Создаём свой, "удобный" ConfigParser
    def __getitem__(self, item):  # Переопределяем получение секции через []
        try:
            return super(MyCfg, self).__getitem__(item)  # Пытаемся вернуть из имеющихся
        except KeyError:  # Если секции нет
            self.add_section(item)  # Создаём её
            return super(MyCfg, self).__getitem__(item)  # И возвращаем


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cfg = MyCfg()
    
    cfg['section']['option'] = 'option_value'
    cfg['section']['tag'] = 'tag_value'

    cfg['another_section']['test'] = 'test_value'

    with open('cfg.ini', 'w') as fp:
        cfg.write(fp)
```

Comment: Почти то что нужно, еще бы скрыть `with open('cfg.ini', 'w') as fp:` `cfg.write(fp)`... Еще вот только не пойму, в данном варианте файл перезаписывается, а как поправить только значение?

Comment: @biomotor Считать, поправить, записать.

Answer (score 2):

Так как `dict` является mutable структурой, то можно провернуть такое:

```py
import json  # Для красивого вывода


class MyDict(dict):  # Наследуемся от dict
    def __getitem__(self, item):  # Переопределяем получение элемента через []
        return self.setdefault(item, MyDict())  # Если значения по ключу нет, 
                                                # создаём ключ со значением=пустой MyDict()
                                                # и возвращаем это значение
                                                # иначе возвращается значение по ключу
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cls = MyDict()
    
    cls['section']['option'] = 'option_value'
    cls['section']['tag'] = 'tag_value'
    
    print(json.dumps(cls, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False))
    print(cls['section']['option'])
```

Вывод:

```
{
    "section": {
        "option": "option_value",
        "tag": "tag_value"
    }
}
option_value
```

Comment: содержание файла .ini в виде: [settings]  <br>  theme='light'

Comment: данный вариант видел, не устраивает общим видом самого json файла, предполагает много { }...

Answer (score 1):

### Вот что получилось в итоге:

```
from configparser import ConfigParser

class MyCfg(ConfigParser):
    def __init__(self, file: str='cfg.ini'):
        self.file = file
        return super(MyCfg, self).__init__()

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        try:
            return super(MyCfg, self).__getitem__(item)
        except KeyError:
            self.add_section(item)
            return super(MyCfg, self).__getitem__(item)

    def read(self):
        return super(MyCfg, self).read(self.file)

    def write(self):
        with open(self.file, 'w') as fp:
            return super(MyCfg, self).write(fp)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cfg = MyCfg('settings.ini')
    cfg.read()
    cfg['section']['option'] = 'option_value'
    cfg['section']['tag'] = 'tag_value'
    cfg['another_section']['test'] = 'test_value'
    cfg.write()
```